# Splitting field of $x^3 +x +1$ over $\mathbb F_{11}$

Tags: polynomials, solution-verification, galois-theory, finite-fields, splitting-field

This is a HW problem for an algebra course.

Determine the splitting field of $f(x)=x^3+x+1$ over $\mathbb F_{11}$.

I tried to use the answers from [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1456900/splitting-field-of-a-polynomial-over-a-finite-field) and [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/430317/splitting-field-of-x3-x-1x4-x-1-over-mathbbf-3) to help me, but want to know if I'm doing it correctly.

**Attempt:** We have that $f(x)$ factors as $(x^2+2x+5)(x+9)$. Since $x+9$ is already a linear factor, we need only concern ourselves with $x^2+2x+5$. We know that $x^2+2x+5$ is irreducible over $\mathbb F_{11}$, so its splitting field will be $\mathbb F_{11^2}$, and hence the splitting field of $f$ is $\mathbb F_{11^2}$.

Is this correct?

Comment: How did you find the factorisation into irreducible factors? Did you check that $x^2+2x+5$ is irreducible? You just write "we know that $x^2+2x+5$ is irreducible". You could also give an argument, what the splitting field $\Bbb F_{11}(a)$ for a root $a$ of it is isomorphic to $\Bbb F_{11^2}$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I agree, that is a gap. I just checked by hand the elements of $\mathbb F_{11}$ to see that $x^2+2x+5$ has no zeroes there.

Comment: I think that you have the correct solution. The question "Is this correct" depends on the grading, i.e., how much detail is required from you.

Comment: You can use that $x^2+2x+5=(x+1)^2+4,$ so it is irreducible because $-1$ is not a square modulo $11.$

Comment: In @ThomasAndrews's comment, I think it's clearer to say that $-4$ is not a square modulo $11$. While they're equivalent, there's another $-1$ in the expression that might be misleading.

Comment: I guess this should'v been in the original question, but does it follow that this extension is of degree $2$ over $\mathbb F_{11}$, because $x^2+2x+5$ is irreducible of degree $2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not hard to show that$\newcommand{\f}{\mathbb{F}_{11}}$
the factor $g:=x^2+2x+5$ is irreducible over $\f$.
Once you have that,
let $\alpha$ be the root of $g$ (in a fixed algebraic closure of $\f$).
Then the splitting field for $f$ over $\f$ is $\f(\alpha)$,
which we know has degree $2$ over $\f$.
This shows that $|\f(\alpha)|=11^2$.
Since finite fields are unique,
we know that $\f(\alpha)=\mathbb{F}_{11^2}$ (in the algebraic closure).

---

I noticed that OP seems to be unsure of the reason why $g$ being quadratic implies the splitting field has degree $2$ over $\f$.
If we have an algebraic closure of a field $F$,
then the splitting field for a polynomial $f$
is simply $F(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n)$,
where $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n$ are the $n$ possibly repeated roots of $f$ in the algebraic closure.

Now, in your case,
the roots of $f$ are $-9$, $\alpha$, $-2-\alpha$,
so the splitting field is $\f(-9, \alpha, -2-\alpha)$,
but then $\f(-9, \alpha, -2-\alpha)=\f(\alpha)$,
which we know is quadratic over $\f$ because of the following theorem:

> Let $K/F$ be an extension. Let $\alpha\in K$ be a root of an irreducible polynomial $f$ of degree $n$.
> Then $F(\alpha)\cong F[x]/(f)$ and $[F(\alpha):F]=n$.